# A question in real anaylsis

Tags: real-analysis

If we let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $[a,b]$ such that,

-there exists a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ where $lim_{n->\infty}f_n(x_0)$ exists
-each $f_n$ is differentiable
-the sequence $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

I want to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$

My logic:

if I use the triangle inequality to write,

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<=|(f_n(x)-f_m(x))-(f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0))|+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|$$

Then I can try and apply the mean value theorem to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$.

Applying the MVT to see the right side above  can be written

$$|(f_n-f_m)'(c)(x-x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)| \le \sup_{[a,b]}|f_n'-f_m'|(b-a)+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|.$$

from here how can I use "uniformly Cauchy" criterion for uniform convergence to prove my problem?

Comment: Try $|f_n (x) - f_m (x)| \leq |f_n (x) - f_n (x_0)| + |f_n (x_0) - f_m (x_0)| + |f_m (x_0) - f_m (x)| $

Comment: I already have this in my answer, so how do I complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f_n'$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, there exists an $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m \geq n \geq N_1$, $$\|f_n' - f_m'\|_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}.$$ In addition, since $\{f_n(x_0)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers, it must be Cauchy. That is, there exists an $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m \geq n \geq N_2$, $$|f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Set $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}.$ Then if $m \geq n \geq N$, we have that $$\|f_n'-f_m'\|_{\infty} (b-a) + |f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}(b-a) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$ so your sequence is Cauchy for any $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: thanks for your submission, do I use this along with my answer I have worked out so far?

Comment: that is a really elementary version of the missing part

Comment: @user456 yes this should complete your argument

Comment: @xk3 Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f_n'$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N_1}$ such that for all $m \geq n \geq N_1$, $$\|f_n' - f_m'\|_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}.$$ this completes my proof correct? the rest is just bonus information?

Comment: Well the bonus information is necessary to show that $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ which is precisely the uniformly cauchy condition. Your argument would look something like this: fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in [a,b]$. Then define the $N$'s above and the use the MVT to show that for all $m, n \geq N$, $$|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$$ and conclude.

Comment: In the end, you want to show that for any given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the uniformly cauchy criterion is satisfied. Then by Nathaniel's comment, since your space is complete, any cauchy sequence converges to an element in that space. In our space, our cauchy sequence $f_n$ must converge to an element $f$, which must be a continuous function.

Comment: @xk3 okay so your latest edit is the final solution?

Comment: Here's how the argument would look: 1. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in [a,b]$. 2. Since $f_n'$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$... (fill in details). 3. Since $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ is convergent... (fill in details). 4. Then by the MVT, for all $m \geq n \geq N$, (do your whole derivation above) < $\epsilon$. 5. Thus $f_n$ is cauchy for all $x \in [a,b]$ and must converge (since your space is complete) to a function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. the Cauchy criterion doesn't care in which space you are as long as the space is complete.
$$\sup_{[a,b]} |f_n'-f_m'| =: \|f_n'-f_m'\|_{C^{0}(a,b)} \to 0$$
if $f_n'$ is a convergent series.

Note that every convergent series is a Cauchy-series and uniform convergence of a series $g_n$ to a limit $g$ means
$$\|g_n-g\|_{C^{0}(a,b)} \to 0 \quad \text{in } \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: so does this complete my solution?

Comment: your solution was already complete. you just need to mention why you righthandside is arbitrary small for a $n,m$ bigger than a certain $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that the righthandside doesn't depend on $x$ anymore. so you could write $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ on the lefthandside instead and everything will work as well

Comment: okay so your submission mentions this? thanks for your help btw